# Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.10.2 iOS when setting signing idenity no provisioning profiles found

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

When I build my Xamarin iOS app and select a signing identity in the project properties, I get "no matching profiles found" in the "Provisioning Profiles" dropdown.  I can see the provisioning profiles in Tools->Options->Xamarin->Apple Accounts->Show Details. I've downloaded all the profiles in my developer account after signing in, yet nothing shows up in the "Provisioning Profiles" drop-down list.  What am I doing wrong?

****Update****

[image]

This is what I see in the bundle signing

[image]

As you can see, I have a ton of provisioning profiles.  Yet none show up in the drop-down list.  I've hit that download button a hundred times.  Frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I did not have a valid distribution profile for distribution to the apple store (even though you can see I did).  I created a new distribution profile and can now see that profile.  But (of course) I have another problem, archiving the bundle never completes.  Look for that questing in another post.  sigh ... it never ends ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Find your actual download address and check if there is a "Provisioning Profiles" file. If there is no such file, try to download again.
2. If the download is unsuccessful, you can download it through Apple Developer.
3. If the "Provisioning Profiles" file exists in the physical address, click to try to open it and check whether it exists in the project.
4. Clean your Xamarin project and run it again.

Comment: Thank you for you reply.  I've cleaned and re-run a hundred times, no changes.  I posted screen shots of what I'm seeing in Visual Studio.  No clue as to whats going on.

Comment: I created a new distribution profile and that one is seen in Visual Studio.  No ide why the others were not.  However, now I have an archiving issue ... it never completes ... this is very frustrating.